# Delete jobs of previous build in sidekiq

Tags: ruby-on-rails, web-deployment, sidekiq, rake-task, faye

I have a long and never ending job i.e rake task that should keep running all the time. (It is faye pub-sub client waiting on server side listening all the time). when application is deployed on server, the job is created and works, but the **problem** here is that, old jobs are not killed in each new build, so when i deploy 2nd time.. there are 2 jobs. and i gone through sidekiq api where we can stop all jobs in queue by finding through worker , but there are other applications running on same server and if i delete all busy jobs, i might end up affecting other applications.

> Here is my worker
>   *app/workers/subscriber.rb*

```
    require 'rake'
    Rake::Task.clear
    Faye::Application.load_tasks
    class Subscriber
      include Sidekiq::Worker
      def perform
        Rake::Task['faye:subscriber'].invoke"
      end
end
```

> Here is my initializers/sidekiq.rb

```
Sidekiq.configure_server do |config| 
    config.redis = { url: 'redis://localhost:6379' }
end

Sidekiq.configure_client do |config|
    config.redis = { url: 'redis://localhost:6379' } 
    Rails.application.config.after_initialize do
        Subscriber.perform_async
    end
end
```

is there any solution ? or am i going in wrong direction ? any help would be greatly appreciated. thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

You are going in the wrong direction.  Sidekiq is not designed for jobs that run forever or constantly.  Create a proper service out of the rake task.

Comment: thanks for reply, any idea what can i use to run the jobs forever?